# Find stiffness of a pre-assumed damped oscillation system from a given dataset

Tags: regression

I am trying to find the stiffness of a damped oscillation system from a given dataset.
I tried to fit a curve to a set of points using curve-fit which is a damped oscillation.
I have tried to give an initial guess to the optimizer but it gives unsatisfactory results.
**The goal is to find the  stiffness of the system and the value at infinite (t).**
An other approach could be eigenvalue but I don't know how to approach it.
Here's the code I used so far, although I am quite sure that it's not the right general approach:

```
x2 = np.arange(len(ppos_p_list))
x2_data = np.array(x2)
def objective(t, a, c, de, phi):
   return a * np.exp(de * t)*cos(phi*t) + c

param_bounds = ([0, 400])
params, params_covariance = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(objective, x2_data, ppos_p_list, p0=(min(ppos_p_list) - max(ppos_p_list), max(ppos_p_list),-1, 150))
plot_ppos_stiff = objective(x2_data, params[0], params[1], params[2], params[3])

fig = plt.figure()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(ppos_p_list, 'o', color='red', markersize=1.5, label='ppos')
ax.plot(plot_ppos_stiff, linestyle='solid', color='red')
```

ppos_p_list data set is

```
[0.932, 0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.203, 0.203, 0.129, 0.527, 0.447, 0.677, 0.991, 0.432, 1.0, 0.535, 0.535, 0.446, 0.853, 0.853, 1.0, 0.789, -0.789, -0.789, -0.695, -0.646, -0.646, -0.563, -1.322, -1.216, -1.275, -1.2, -1.099, -1.134, -1.173, -1.145, -1.113, -0.835, 1.0, 0.862, 0.862, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.585, 0.533, 0.786, 0.639, 0.409, 0.508, 0.508, 0.571, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.872, 1.0, 0.94, 0.855, 0.855, 0.939, 0.939, 0.999, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.866, 0.93, 0.892, 0.892, 0.868, 0.741, 0.761, 0.761, 0.761, 0.761, 0.749, 0.923, 0.764, 0.751, 0.798, 1.0, 1.0, 0.599, 0.599, 0.637, 0.637, 0.623, 0.614, 0.606, 0.534, 0.51, 0.532, 0.515, 0.522, 0.513, 0.581, 0.632, 0.617, 0.598, 0.592, 0.592, 0.592, 0.586, 0.586, 0.58, 0.607, 0.607, 0.613, 0.64, 0.624, 0.671, 0.662, 0.676, 0.679, 0.619, 0.619, 0.59, 0.619, 0.607, 0.607, 0.607, 0.595, 0.589, 0.61, 0.633, 0.673, 0.663, 0.807, 0.85, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.987, 0.971, 0.993, 0.97, 0.946, 0.928, 0.953, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.986, 0.986, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.948, 0.948, 1.0, 0.925, 0.9, 0.867, 0.867, 0.874, 0.864, 0.864, 0.864, 0.847, 0.832, 0.892, 0.881, 0.881, 0.881, 0.886, 0.868, 0.88, 0.88, 0.872, 0.875, 0.885, 0.942, 0.942, 0.976, 1.0, 0.984, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.988, 0.957, 0.957, 0.926, 0.935, 0.968, 0.989, 0.983, 1.0, 1.0, 0.955, 0.955, 0.955, 0.946, 0.955, 0.946, 0.956, 0.944, 0.944, 0.944, 0.954, 0.935, 0.928, 0.936, 0.927, 0.895, 0.901, 0.891, 0.9, 0.927, 0.927, 0.927, 0.914, 0.912, 0.91, 0.917, 0.912, 0.928, 0.959, 0.954, 0.964, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.931, 0.931, 0.934, 0.96, 1.0, 1.0, 0.994, 1.0, 1.0, 0.99, 0.985, 0.982, 1.0]
```

[image]

Comment: These data do not exhibit a damped oscillation.  (Yes, they're damped in some evident visual sense, but they don't follow a damped oscillation model.)  If you could explain what they mean and how they are measured, we might be able to suggest appropriate models and fitting procedures.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes, It's not a per-say damped oscilaltion because it is caped at 1 and aperiodic in this case. If I could just extract the exponnential part of the movment (A and de in the equation) which translates the damping, it will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer and sharing it with other who would need it:
Step 1/ find the peaks using find_peaks from scipy
Step 2/ curve_fitting giving 1st guess as the first peak minus the max of the value for a, the max value for c and -0.01 for de.

```
def objective(t, a, c, de):
  return a * np.exp(de * t) + c


x2 = np.arange(len(ppos_p_list))
x = np.array(poly_data)[:, 0]
y = np.array(poly_data)[:, 1]

params, params_covariance = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(objective, x, y, p0 = (w_ppos[0][1] - 1, 1, -0.01))
plot_ppos_stiff_extr = objective(x2, params[0], params[1], params[2])
```

[image]

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, then please consider 
[upvoting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) 
and/or 
[accepting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) 
it.